# Can one add a comment to a pull request by email in Github?

Tags: github

Github lets you [reply to comments by email](https://github.com/blog/811-reply-to-comments-from-email), but I can't find a documentation saying that you can directly comment a line of code or a commit by sending an email to some github address.

I often do code reviews while traveling by train or plane, where internet connection is not available. I would like to write a bunch of comments with my email client in separate emails and send them as soon as I have internet again. I don't know if this is feasible or not.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can comment on the pull request via email by answering the pull request notification email if you're [watching the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/about-notifications/), I don't think you can comment on a specific file or line of code.